# How do I configure maven-cobertura-plugin to instrument a dependency jar

Tags: maven, cobertura

I have classes in two modules. One of the modules contains some integration tests that exercise some classes from the other module. I would like my coverage reports to include classes from both modules but I can't find out how to configure the cobertura plugin so that it will instrument the other module's jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible: the unit tests metrics for project A should be complete on their own without executing anything from project B. Unit tests should be written in a manner to cover the code completely. However you may consider re-using the testing code between A and B (see `test-jar` goal  of `maven-jar-plugin`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. These are not unit tests, they are end-to-end system tests. There's no valid reason why they should not be executing code in another project. But it doesn't look like the maven plugin makes this possible.

Comment: Yes, these are integration tests. Integration tests usually form a separate project (e.g. T) which is "run" after all projects are build (e.g. A, B), all unit tests run and obviously all statistics has been created. More over Hudson already has archived the artifacts and statistics data. Now you want What you want from `cobertura` in project T is to go back to project A and alter the data somehow. This is not possible. If that is possible statistics for A will be different depending on weather T was run or not.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. I'm not looking for project T to alter the stats produced by the tests in project A. I have tests in project T that exercise classes from project A and I want to see how much coverage those tests produce. All I need to achieve this is for project A's jar file, while on project T's classpath, to be instrumented.  The reports from project T are independent from the reports produced by project A.

Comment: Now I understand what you need. You need classes in project A to be instrumented and included in test report for T. In this sense my reply is not correct, I agree. I think that technically it is possible, however `cobertura` does not have access to the sources, but it can generate metrics for these classes... What you need is a kind of package or dependency filter for that, as `cobertura` needs to know what exactly to instrument additionally (in order not to instrument everything)...

Comment: I have a similar case with a multi-module Maven project. Various modules have a common dependency. Which is why it became a separate module. When running Cobertura on the separate modules they don't show any coverage of the common module. So I have no clue about the testing done for the common module. I think it's just a matter of instrumenting those classes too, but I can't seem to get Cobertura to include them.

Comment: Perhaps Hudson's [Aggregate downstream test results](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/wp-content/images/hudson-config.jpg) can help... "Setting test aggregation is a convenient way of collecting all the test results from such downstream test jobs and display it along with the build that they are testing. In this way, people can see the overall test status of the given build quickly." I am very unsure it will include also Cobertura statistics.